# ¿Cuál es la función de la @ delante de expresiones en PHP?

Tags: php

Mirando por la documentación de PHP me he encontrado algo que no había visto nunca. Anteponer una `@` a una expresión para que ignore, si se producen, mensajes de error.

Ejemplo:

```
//Si no tenemos la $key, va a dar un error y el programa lo va a ignorar
$valor = @$valores[$key];
```

El problema, o lo que yo veo como un problema, es que poner la `@` puede dar motivos a grandes fallos de seguridad, ya que está ignorando cualquier error que se produzca en tu aplicación.

Para más inri, actualmente también ignora errores críticos como indica en la [documentación](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php):

> **Advertencia:**
>   En la actualidad, el operador de prefijo "@" para control de errores deshabilitará incluso el reporte de errores en casos de fallos críticos que terminarán la ejecución del script. Entre otras cosas, esto quiere decir que si se usa "@" para eliminar los errores de una cierta función y ésta no se encuentra disponible o ha sido escrita de forma incorrecta, el script se detendrá en ese punto sin indicación de por qué.

La verdad que se me hace muy difícil pensar en un entorno de producción ignorando los errores que aparecen en la aplicación. Incluso en entorno de pruebas, en el que incluso sería más necesario el tener un buen control de los errores para poder corregirlos de una manera mucho más sencilla.

De hecho, he visto que con la función [`set_error_handler`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php) puedes realizar un control de errores personalizado. Sin embargo, si usas la `@` delante de tus expresiones, esta simplemente devolverá cero.

Por lo tanto, me han surgido varias dudas respecto a este operador de control de errores:

- ¿Tiene alguna función más aparte que la de ignorar errores en el programa?
- ¿Es utilizada la `@` en entornos de producción?
- Y relacionada con lo anterior, ¿hay en algún caso en el que se requiera la utilización de este operador? Es decir, ¿sería útil utilizar este operador en algún caso concreto?

Comment: Hasta ahora yo tenia entendido exactamente lo que tu comentas, no creo que se le pueda dar otro uso que no sea ignorar errores. Sin embargo leyendo las contribuciones de otros usuarios esto es obsoleto, se ocupaba antiguamente, me imagino que con otros controles con los cuales podemos encapsular errores y controlarlos en nuestra aplicacion. Respecto a utilizarlo en produccion no me cabe la menor duda de que esto JAMAS debe utilizarse en produccion no solo por fallas de seguridad si no tambien de fallas logicas y algoritmicas que pueden hacer otro tipo de errores.

Comment: @sioesi Sí, estoy totalmente de acuerdo contigo. Yo lo primero que he hecho ha sido ir a ver las contribuciones de los usuarios. Por eso, y porque nada más verlo me ha levantado curiosidad, he querido hacer esta pregunta. No me cabe en la cabeza ninguna posibilidad en la que se pueda usar esta funcionalidad. Además, como no está deprecated ni nada, pues me ha entrado todavía más curiosidad por si realmente hay algún uso específico para este control de errores.

Comment: Me imagino que aun no esta deprecated porque usuarios en desarrollo lo deben ocupar para testear código en caso de alguna inyección anormal o simplemente para ver el comportamiento o seguridad de su código. Voy a estar atento a los comentarios ya que me dejaste con la duda igual jajaja

Answer (score 12):

> ¿Cuál es la función de la @ delante de expresiones en PHP?

Suprime los mensajes de error, incluye noticia (Notice), advertencia (Warning) y errores críticos (critical errors).

> ¿Tiene alguna función más aparte que la de ignorar errores en el programa?

No.

> ¿Es utilizada la @ en entornos de producción?

Sí y No. Depende del desarrollador.

> Y relacionada con lo anterior, ¿hay en algún caso en el que se
>   requiera la utilización de este operador? Es decir, ¿sería útil
>   utilizar este operador en algún caso concreto?

Por una razón se lanza un error y si se muestra ese error al usuario puede ser finalmente peligroso, por esa razón se debería tratar los errores correctamente.

O sea.. Ignorar con `@` no sería lo ideal ni aconsejable, en vez puedes ignorar/suprimir los errores mediante `php.ini` y/o definir/tratar los errores con [set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/es/function.set-error-handler.php).

Comment: Muchas gracias @aldanux. Aunque sinceramente lo de "depende del desarrollador" no me convence mucho. Es como decir: ¿son seguros los coches? Depende de si te pones el cinturón de seguridad o no. Yo me refería a respuestas en el sentido de que tuvieran una función específica ne entornos de producción, lo cual me extrañaba, pero podría ser. De todas formas, si no te importa, voy a dejar la pregunta abierta durante un tiempo más para ver si hay alguien que responde que ha utilizado este método realmente con alguna funcionalidad en especial. De momento +1 :)

Comment: @Error404 - Es que eso ya depende de cada desarrollador cuales tendrán sus razones para usar `@` o no... No está prohibido de usarlo ni hace *daño*... pero lo de siempre: si trabajas con mucho desarrolladores en un proyecto grande pues imagínate el chaos que se puede producir.... si trabajas solo haz lo que quieras... ;)

Comment: Aún así le sigo sin ver la funcionalidad. Imagínate que se te bloquea el programa a mitad. Vale, el usuario no verá el error, pero también se le quedará la pantalla bloqueada con lo que esté haciendo y encima sin ningún mensaje. No sé, lo veo algo totalmente prescindible.

Comment: @Error404 -  Utilidad lo puedes ver en cuando estés en el **proceso de desarrollo**..

Comment: @Error404 entrar en ver como se usa este operador sería entrar en opiniones personales de funcionalidad. Lo usarán para ahorrar tiempo o no tratar los errores debidamente (que también es cuestionable de si es correcto o no), o por que los errores no son graves y no influyen, o no alteran de forma anormal el proceso del script, u otros muchos motivos... es bastante complejo decir que es correcto o no en el uso de este operador. Al final la responsabilidad de uso cae en el desarrollador. Como ejemplo de uso, sin ir más lejos, puedes encontrarlos en los `scripts` de _Wordpress_...

Comment: @OscarR. Sí, realmente mi duda no era si dependía del desarrollador o no sino si se usaba para algún caso concreto en entornos de producción. Por supuesto, siempre depende del desarrollador pero hay algunas veces que algunos métodos no se usan casi nunca y para casos concretos vienen muy bien utilizarlos. Ahí estaba mi duda, aunque creo que realmente evitaré a toda costa usar este operador en mis scripts, ya que no estoy viendo que tenga ningún otro uso que el que es evidente

Comment: La funcionalidad es la que te han dicho, omitir errores, y se usa cuando una llamada a una función es susceptible de levantar un error pero en la ejecución de tu código te da igual y quieres que siga adelante, entonces, ciertamente @aldanux tienen razón, depende de si un programador quiere hacerlo así o controlar el error de una forma más adecuada. Yo sí me la he encontrado en entornos de producción, y te puedo decir que casi siempre, por una u otra razón, hemos acabado por "corregirlo". Se considera una muy mala práctica.

Comment: Si bien no es una práctica recomendable a veces es necesaria. El caso específico que me viene a la mente es el de mysql_connect que cuando fallaba la conexión a la BBDD devolvía false y generaba un warning interrumpiendo la ejecución del script. En este caso se utilizaba la @ para suprimir el warning y se utilizaba un if para manejar de forma más "limpia" el informe del problema de conexión.

Answer (score 1):

**¿Tiene alguna función más aparte que la de ignorar errores en el programa?**

No, en realidad es su única función, la mayor parte de la descripción de este operador ya lo describiste tu.

**¿Es utilizada la @ en entornos de producción?**

Los entornos de producción por lo general PHP desactiva los errores solo, al detectar que no es una IP local. Lo único que no podrá suprimir este operador son los errores de navegador, por ejemplo el `404`. Si tu código tiene un error en un entorno de producción por lo general retornará un código de estado [500](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anexo:C%C3%B3digos_de_estado_HTTP)
Si deseas activar la traza de errores, puedes hacerlo sobre el mismo script

```
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

O por medio de php.ini de forma generalizada

```
display_errors = on
```

A este nivel si mostrará los errores en tu script, pero ¿A que usuarios les gustaría ver un error dónde programaste mal un índice de un array?
Por ejemplo

```
$array = array( 'foo', 'bar' );
echo $array[2];
```

Aquí habrá un error como tu ya lo describiste, y es en este punto donde puedes invocar al salvavidas `@`

Considero que la respuesta de @aldanux es correcta, el usar el operador depende del expertise del desarrollador para controlar errores. (Aunque es el método más feo)

**Y relacionada con lo anterior, ¿hay en algún caso en el que se requiera la utilización de este operador? Es decir, ¿sería útil utilizar este operador en algún caso concreto?**

Si, yo lo he usado para dar mantenimiento crítico, por ejemplo

```
Tabla USUARIOS
ID | PAISES_VISITADOS
1  | México, Colombia, Dinamarca
2  | Bélgica, Singapur, Rusia
3  | Canadá, España

$query  = "SELECT PAISES_VISITADOS FROM USUARIOS";
$result = mysqli_query( $con, $query );
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
  $exp = explode(',', $row['PAISES_VISITADOS']);
  echo 'Pais Visitado 1:' . $exp[0] . '<br>';
  echo 'Pais Visitado 2:' . $exp[1] . '<br>';
  echo 'Pais Visitado 3:' . $exp[2] . '<br>';
}
```

Esto marcaría un error en el último registro, por que no tiene un índice 2, sólo hay 2 valores en la cadena. Ahora puedes evitar ese error con un `@`

```
while( $row = mysqli_fetch_array( $result ) ){
 $exp = explode(',', $row['PAISES_VISITADOS']);
 echo 'Pais Visitado 1:' . @$exp[0] . '<br>';
 echo 'Pais Visitado 2:' . @$exp[1] . '<br>';
 echo 'Pais Visitado 3:' . @$exp[2] . '<br>';
}
```

Es una forma 'Sucia' de corregirlo, pero es válido para fixes muuuuy urgentes.
El efecto puede repercutir en una aplicación dependiendo del ecosistema que se desarrolle, por ejemplo un sistema de TEMPLATES podrías ver un error feo en la pantalla, sin embargo una API que retorne un JSON y esté mal construido, generará un error del lado del cliente, imaginando que se usa AJAX, el sistema se quedará pegado pensando, por que la respuesta no es un JSON puro, si no que tiene una cadena con un error.

En una API no es lo mismo recibir:

```
{data:'this is data', success: true};
```

A recibir

```
E_NOTICE : type 8 -- Undefined offset: 2 -- at line 3
{data:'this is data', success: true};
```

El sistema que parsea la información a objetos en JS no sabrá que hacer,

Espero pueda ser de gran aporte esto.

Saludos

Comment: Alberto debo decir que el ejemplo de `PAISES_VISITADOS` que pones para justificar el uso de `@` es muy muy malo. En ese caso el error está en la forma no flexible en que lees los datos. Bastaría con abrir un bucle y hacer un `explode` sobre la columna, sacando en cada caso los valores exactos que haya... Yo creo que el uso de `@` no es justificado en casi ningún contexto hoy día.

Answer (score 0):

> ¿Tiene alguna función más aparte que la de ignorar errores en el programa?

No.

> ¿Es utilizada la @ en entornos de producción?

Sí, en casos aislados. No lo recomiendo.

> Y relacionada con lo anterior, ¿hay en algún caso en el que se requiera la utilización de este operador? Es decir, ¿sería útil utilizar este operador en algún caso concreto?

Existe una situación clara y concreta en donde el @ debe ser usado de forma obligatoria, es una situación un poco irónica, pero es lógica; y **es cuando el error que se te está mostrando es incorrecto**. Puede sonar absurdo, pero por lógica un intérprete de errores también puede llegar a tener errores.