# PHP/Java: ¿Qué significa el uso de @ en PHP? ¿Tiene Java algún equivalente?

Tags: java, php

Esta pregunta surgió de un problema planteado por un usuario de este sitio.

En PHP se usan expresiones del tipo:

```
if ($var == "Uno" || @intval($var1) == 1){
    echo "Picked 1";
}
```

¿Qué significa la @ usada en `@intval($var1)`?

¿Hay algún equivalente en Java?

Comment: Contestado parcialmente a tu primera pregunta: http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/31962/6491

Comment: En resumen: En PHP el caracter `@` se usa para hacer un bypass de errores y en Java se usa para usar anotaciones (o decoraciones en algunos lenguajes).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El @ antes de una expresión o comando funciona como [supresor de errores](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php). Si la ejecución de la expresión o comando provoca un error, el programa fallará silenciosamente, siguiendo su curso sin que nadie sepa que algo salió mal.

El supresor de errores es una **muy mala práctica**, porque te hace imposible debuguear tu código. En la práctica, según los cambios que hagas antes de la expresión silenciada, el error que estás suprimiendo puede ir cambiando y tú no tendrás cómo enterarte.

Usando el ejemplo típico:

```
function getHandle(file) {

    ...algunos comandos...

    $handle = fopen(file,r);

    return $handle;
}
```

Si ese archivo no existe el programa genera un error tipo `E_WARNING`, por lo que, en los años 2000 - 2006 se manejaba a la manera

```
function getHandle(file) {

    ...algunos comandos...

    $handle = @fopen(file,r);

    return $handle;
}
```

Si el archivo no existe, simplemente comprobamos si `$handle` no es igual a `false`.

Entonces, algunos iban más allá y para ahorrar problemas escribían por ejemplo:

```
$handle = @getHandle('archivo.txt');
```

Y suprimiendo los errores de una función **suprimes cualquier error que haya dentro de ella**. No tienes cómo saber si falló el `fopen` o alguno de los otros comandos. ¿Cómo debuggear eso?

Así, sucesivamente, se usó el supresor de errores para acallar secciones enteras del código que luego no funcionaba y nadie entendía por qué.

La manera correcta de hacer esto sería, en cambio, capturar el fallo en una excepción, usando `try...catch` pero...

¿Qué se hace cuando la expresión **no tira una excepción** sino que falla estrepitosamente?

Bueno, simplemente no dejar que getHandle tire un E_WARNING, ni tampoco suprimirlo, sino manejar el error y levantar una excepción tú mismo:

```
function getHandle(file) {

    ...algunos comandos...

    if(is_readable(file)) {
      $handle = fopen(file,r);

      ... otros comandos ...

      return $handle;

    } else {
     throw new \Exception('el archivo no existe');
    }
}
```

Y al llamar a `getHandle` podrías envolver, ahora sí, en un bloque `try / catch`.

```
try {
  $handle = getHandle('archivo.txt');
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    echo "La función ha fallado con mensaje: ".$e->getMessage();
}
```

En este caso sabrías exactamente por qué falló. Y si dentro de la función `getHandle` hay 10 cosas que pueden romperse, cada una podrá tirar su propia excepción con un mensaje descriptivo.

Te das cuenta de la diferencia? En vez de dejar que ocurra un error, que interrumpe el flujo, o suprimirlo con resultados impredecibles, lo atrapas y haces algo que cambie el flujo del programa. De esa manera no hay programas que corren y programas que se caen, sino sólo programas que corren de una manera distinta acorde a lo que van encontrando.

En las versiones actuales de los frameworks más populares, se usan custom error handlers que convierten los errores en excepciones, de manera que todo error termina convertido en excepción y puedes usar `try/catch` a destajo.

Lo peligroso de esto es que una excepción no atrapada siempre es un error `E_FATAL`, por lo que al usar esos ErrorHandlers hay que ser muy meticuloso con el uso de try...catch.

Respecto a tu segunda pregunta: lenguajes más robustos como Java, C# o Python no tienen este defecto de PHP respecto a la dualidad entre errores y excepciones (PHP tiene muchas dualidades que son su principal defecto), por lo que tu abanico de posibilidades se limita a atrapar la excepción o cruzar los dedos.

En general en ese tipo de lenguajes puedes regular la verbosidad del error para mostrar menos errores en pantalla y mandarlos directo al log, para no exponer al usuario final información destinada al debug. El equivalente de suprimir los errores sería establecer que el log de errores se escribe en `/dev/null`.

Comment: +1 Excelente respuesta. Gracias.

Answer (score 3):

> el signo de arroba (@). Cuando se antepone a una expresión en PHP, cualquier mensaje de error que pueden ser generado por esa expresión será ignorado.
>   [Fuente](http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Tengo entendido que no existe algo así en java sin embargo hay una que otra maña, en java 8 por ejemplo he visto usar expresiones lambda conjunto ha algo parecido al patrón command (command pattern)

[Checa esta respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28659553/3926480)

Answer (score 1):

Como te ha comentado **Malcam**  el **@** en php ayuda  a que en caso de un error este no se levante y ocacione una excepcion en nuestro codigo php en caso de un error, es muy similar a cuando usas un try{} catch(){} y tu codigo esta dentro del try y este genera un error pero en el catch solo dejas en blanco la seccion dentro de el

```
try {
        ...         
    } catch (Exception  $ignoreexcepcion) {
        echo "Si dejo esta parte vacia no mostrara el error";
    }
```

y como ya sabras en java tambien es posible el uso de try catch

```
  try {
            ...         
        } catch (ignoreexcepcion) {
            alert("Excepcion en mi codigo";
        }
```

Aunque va contra las buenas practicas de programacion dejar un catch vacio algunas veces es la mejor solucion mientras encuentras la correcta :D

PD: no conozco una equivalente directa en java para la funcion que realiza el @ en php.

http://php.net/manual/es/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

http://php.net/manual/es/language.exceptions.php

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Pero en la segunda parte no pregunto por un equivalente en Javascript, sino en **Java**.

Comment: Muy cierto. pero aun asi no conozco tampoco un equivalente en Java.